# valor de botón presionado en modal

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

como obtener el valor de un botón que se presiono en una ventana modal?, lo he intentado de esta forma

```js
$('#modalPregunta').on('show.bs.modal', function (evnt) {
  
var btnn = $(evnt.relatedTarget).find('button').val();          


});
```

Pero me sale undefined, mis botones son simples

```html
<button type="button" id="btnsi" class="btn btn-primary" value="si">Si</button>
<button type="button" id="btnno" class="btn btn-danger" value="no">No</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te paso es que son necesarias las propiedades `data-toggle` y `data-target` del `button` para que te tome el value con el `relatedTarget`.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Button trigger modal -->  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="si">
    Si
  </button>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="no">
    No
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <!--<div class="modal-footer">

        </div>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (evnt) {

        var valueBottom = $(evnt.relatedTarget).val();
        console.log(valueBottom);       

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pero el `relatedTarget` ya es el boton, no necesitas hacer el find()

```
$('#modalPregunta').on('show.bs.modal', function (evnt) {

    var btnValue = $(evnt.relatedTarget).val();          
    alert(btnValue);

});
```

Comment: me sigue saliendo undefined, si le quito el .val() me imprime [object][object] unicamente

Comment: si usas var btnValue = $(evnt.relatedTarget).text(); que obtienes ?

Comment: no marca undefined pero no aparece ningún valor como si estuviera vacio

Comment: es muy raro lo que esta sucediendo, no te animas a usar el developer tools del browser, si usas Chrome, accedes con F12, puedes mediente la solapa "Sources" poner un breakpoint en el javascript para que se detenga el codigo he inspeccionar que valor toma relatedTarget

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione colocándole otros atributos ( data-toggle, data-target, data-whatever) a los botones quedando de la siguiente forma

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="si">si</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="no">no</button>
```

y recuperando el valor así

```js
$('#modalPregunta').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var recipient = button.data('whatever');

})
```